# Try/Except block in a function returns None on exception: will this still run the Finally block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently attempting to write the second part of a quiz program, which uses a simple function `load_quiz` to load a .json file containing the quiz data, and if a file is not found or is empty it will simply return nothing and refuse playing the quiz.

My code is as follows:

```
def load_quiz():

    quiz = None
    try:
        with open('quiz.json', 'r') as f:
            quiz = json.load(f)
    except (OSError, ValueError):
        print("Quiz file not found/empty! Please load an unemptied quiz .JSON in order to play.")
        return None
    finally:
        if quiz and quiz[playable]:
            play_quiz(f)
        else:
            print("Quiz file invalid! Please load a valid .JSON in order to play.")
            return None
```

What I'm wondering is if this approach would even work. If the function returns `None` within the `except` block, will that still execute whatever is in the `finally` block, or will the function simply stop there? If not, then how would I go around that?

**Is this a viable option?**

Comment: `finally` *always* gets executed, but I think you want `else`. Or just continue the function outside the `try`, as it will end before that in the failing case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's exactly what I was thinking to do otherwise. If you'd like, you can turn that into an answer?

Comment: This is not a good application of `finally`. It should be used when you want the code to run regardless of exception. In your case, you don't want the quiz to run. So, remove the `finally` block and turn `if quiz and quiz[playable]:` into `if quiz[playable]:` ... otherwise, if the file doesn't exist you get both error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird Try-Except-Else-Finally behavior with Return statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164144/weird-try-except-else-finally-behavior-with-return-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this function:

```
def divide(x, y):
    try:
        return x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
    finally:
        print('always')
```

The `finally` will be executed in the case without an exception:

```
>>> divide(1, 2)
always
0.5
```

and in the case the exception got raised and caught:

```
>>> divide(1, 0)
always
0
```

As you can see, the `always` is printed before the return of the function, even though visually the `return` comes before the `finally`.

Answer (score 1):

> The `finally` clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the `try` statement is left via a `break`, `continue` or `return` statement.

<sup>https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block still gets executed. In fact, it gets executed before the return statement in the `except` block is executed. Hence you will get a None value returned from the `finally` block not from the `except` block.