# Why 'try/finally' interacts strangely with 'return' in Python?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain me why does this work like it does? Python 3.6.3

```
In [1]: def test():
   ...:     try:
   ...:         return 1
   ...:     finally:
   ...:         return 2
   ...:     

In [2]: test()
Out[2]: 2
```

**EDIT:**
This is not exactly duplicate as linked questions raise exceptions in their `try :` and my example uses `return` which I expected to work. This function looks like it should return 1 yet it returns 2 - so basically `return 1` is ignored. `finally` makes a good job of eating any risen exceptions but should it also eat returns?

Comment: As `finally` will be executed without any exception, I think in this case the statement in `try` is executed but the value doesn't return.

Comment: This answer in the duplicate is valid both for `return` and for exceptions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164157/1977847

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because finally is a cleaning up action that is always excuted if added in a try, except,else, finally ;)

You can read Python 3 documentation’s page on Error handlings here:https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Section: 8.6. Defining Clean-up Actions