# Nested try-except-finally not working as expected

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have the following sample function:

```
def test():
    try:
        try:
            x =1
        except:
            x = 2
        finally:
            print('X')
            x = 7
            return x
    except Exception:
        x=2
    finally:
        x = 9
        return x

print(test())
```

Based on this, I would expect that test() always returns 7 (first return), but instead it returns 9, even though it reached the x=7 line ('X' is printed). How can this be?

Comment: May be this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164144/weird-try-except-else-finally-behavior-with-return-statements/11164157) would be helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

> If a finally clause is present, the finally clause will execute as the
>   last task before the try statement completes. The finally clause runs
>   whether or not the try statement produces an exception.
>
> (...)
>
> - **If a finally clause includes a return statement, the returned value      will be the one from the finally clause’s return statement, not the
>
>     value from the try clause’s return statement.**

you may think that you have 2 `finally` clauses but the first one is included in the first `try` clause so  it does make sense that your function returns   `9`